# magento order mixup with other order

Tags: magento-1.9

I have facing order issue with magento version (1.9.0.1). I have placed a order from front-end and checked in my account order page as well in backend order page it showing another product with my order. I have order only one product but it showing 2 product in order. Total amount is correct but another user billing and shipping address showing. Where is an issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you deleted your test order ever ?

Comment: No and it has issue with multiple orders not for all.